# Reset password for user who registered with Social Auth (Google) [Django, Djoser, Social Auth]

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser, social-auth-app-django

I am trying to using custom model with Djoser JWT endpoint but I want to reset the password for those user who register with Google OAuth.
When I am using the [API](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/base_endpoints.html#reset-password) endpoint the password reset mail is not getting send to mail.

```py
@action(["post"], detail=False)
def reset_password(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.get_user()
    if user:
            context = {"user": user}
            to = [get_user_email(user)]
            settings.EMAIL.password_reset(self.request, context).send(to)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In the above code when i am following the default procedure i.e., email password for that it is working but when i am trying to reset password for the user who came through SSO for them i am not able to reset the password in that case i am getting `user = serializer.get_user()` as `None` but in my dB i can the person's entry (email field).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

I tried to alter the reset password to get the email ID but i am not able to fetch the Email ID from custom user model.

Comment: Could you share a piece of code for we know what is going wrong?

Comment: @claudius the code where i'm resetting the password code looks like as i mentioned above

Comment: Please clarify your problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Could you provide more info by printing out the DRF View, the Serializer, and the `request.data`?